# Javascript to provide incremented value to page on separate host

Tags: javascript, counter

Visitors to a website are completing a survey written in HTML. However, I cannot store values across surveys. In one portion of the survey, each user must be shown a unique set of objects, which are stored in a table.

To determine which set of objects a given subject is to see, I'd like to write something on another host which gets silently called as users go through the survey. On each call, the script [1] returns a value then [2] increments to the value it will return to the next user.

How would I go about doing this with javascript?

Comment: Not sure I understand fully, can you not use local storage to store values across surveys?

Comment: Exactly, silly as that may be.

Comment: How many objects you have in total, and how many of those you show in a survey? Couldn't a random pick help you out?

Comment: It would, but we need each of about ~1000 combinations to be shown to at least one person. So relying on a random draw would really increase the number of participants we need.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cookies.  However if the user has cookies turned off then you would want to use server side scripting and the Session Object to pass this information.

To write the cookie

```
document.cookie="count=" + countvariable;
```

Reading the Cookie

I would use this function

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

countvariable = parseint(getCookie("count"));
```

This would return an integer value of the count which you would just increment and rewrite using the first line of code again.